# How to make data available in all scopes in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I wish to fetch data from the server-side using `$http` and and make it available to the all routes and controllers in my app.

Javascript code sample

```
myApp.factory('menuService', function($http){

 $http.get('/pages').success(function(data){

        return data; //list of pages
    });
});

myApp.run(function($rootScope, menuService){

    $rootScope.menu = menuService;
});
```

HTML code sample

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="page in menu">{{page.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

This code actually returns the data but does not print it on my html page. Please can someone help? Thanks

Comment: I don't think data act as a list of pages, not for the factory anyway, only for the success. Can't you wrap the data into a variable of the menu service and bind it to the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to benefit from setting up your `menuService` a bit different. Try the following...

```
myApp.factory('menuService', function($http) {

    function getData() {
        return $http.get('/pages');
    }

    return {
        'getData' : getData
    }
});
```

Now we have a function wrapped in our `$http` call in a `getData()` function,  we can now easily leverage `then()` to resolve the promise returned by `getData()` in `.run()`, ensuring we get a resolved value and `$rootScope.menu` gets assigned the values we want. This new setup on `menuService` now sets the landscape to add other functions at later times, which we'll likely want.

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, menuService) {
    menuService.getData().then(function(response) {
        $rootScope.menu = response;
    })
});
```

Check out the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs for a better understanding on asynchronous behavior

Comment: Your answer is the same as the first one. it is actually good.

Comment: It's slightly different. If you set up `menuService` this way, you'll have room to grow it with other functions using the revealing module pattern. I tried to elaborate on why this is happening and included further resources. I wouldn't chalk that up as the the same answer

Answer (score 3):

You are inverting the differed promise pattern.

Instead your code should be:

```
myApp.factory('menuService', function($http){

     return $http.get('/pages');


});

myApp.run(function($rootScope, menuService){

     menuService.then(function(data) {
          $rootScope.menu = data;
    }) 
});
```

Comment: I understand the logic in your code and for some reason I do not know, I do not still have my data printed on screen as expected. I wish to know if there is any modifications I need to do at the level of my html.

Comment: I finally got the desired result by replacing `.then()` with `.success()` such that we have        ` myApp.run(function($rootScope, menuService){   menuService.success(function(data){ $rootScope.menu = data;})  });`

Comment: @TheOracle if you had used the approach I recommended you could have kept `then` because of the returned promise